# Cross-platform embedded database/key-value store for C#

Tags: c#, .net, nosql, embedded-database

I'm looking for a fast, embeddable key/value store with cursor semantics over key collections (or a simple embeddable DB) that I can use in .NET and mono. Need it to be open-source, would prefer an MIT or Apache style license over a GPL license. Not opposed to a library that needs bindings to be written, as long as binaries are available for both windows and linux.

Options considered:

- SQLite - has bindings and native implementation, but single-threaded and not all that fast
- Embedded InnoDB - no .NET bindings i can find and it's GPLv2
- Berkley DB - no .NET bindings i can find
- Tokyo Cabinet - no .NET bindings i can find and problematic to build on windows
- MadCow Memory-mapped data structures - GPLv2

Is there an option better than the above that i'm missing, or bindings for the above i don't know about?

**UPDATE**: Used Oracle's official BDB bindings with 4.8 and 5.0 but couldn't get them working under mono. Also had some other issues (C# drivers for BDB are still immature). Wrote a BitCask inspired K/V store called Firkin ( http://github.com/sdether/Firkin ) store and using that now instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick search for Berkeley DB Bindings for C# turned up - [Berkeley DB for .NET](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libdb-dotnet/)

Comment: Well don't i feel like an idiot. How did i not find that before.

Comment: It happens to the best of us from time to time.

Comment: The 4.8 release BerkeleyDb from Oracle actually comes with an official C# API.

Answer (score 1):

i vote for Berkley DB. it is very fast and [wrapper](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libdb-dotnet/) is good. i used it a lot